# For which $a$, $b > 0$ is $f:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^2}$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, asymptotics, lebesgue-integral

This problem was part of an Analysis exam on Lebesgue integration:

For which $a$, $b > 0$ is $f:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^2}$ integrable?

We were taught to solve these kind of questions using arguments like $f(x)=\Theta(\frac{1}{x^\delta})$, $f(x)=\text{O}(\frac{1}{x^\delta})$ or $f(x)=\Omega(\frac{1}{x^\delta})$ for $x\to 0$ or $x\to\infty$  for some $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ (Landau Notation), but I can't seem to find $a,b >0$ such that integrability can be assured for $x\to 0$ and $x\to\infty$.

Here is an attempt I made; Suppose $a\geq b$ without loss of generality. Then for $x\to 0$ we have that $$f(x)=\Theta\left(\frac{1}{x^{2a}}\right) \hspace{2mm}\text{for }x\to0$$
giving us integrability for $x\to 0$ iff $\alpha<1/2$. But for $x\to\infty$ we also have: $$f(x)=\Theta\left(\frac{1}{x^{2a}}\right) \hspace{2mm}\text{for }x\to\infty$$
so if we want integrability for $x\to\infty$ we need that $\alpha>1/2$, which is not possible.

I know I am missing some important subtlety here but I can't seem to find it. I would greatly appreciate a push in the right direction.

Kind regards,
Jef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $a>b$; equality is impossible. Near the origin, small powers are good and at infinity, big powers are good. For $x$ small to get the desired control just bound
$$ \frac1{x^a+x^b}\le \frac1{x^b}$$
And for $x$ large
$$ \frac1{x^a+x^b}\le \frac1{x^a}$$
This gives $2b<1<2a$. The above follows from $x^a>0$; to get the big theta lower bound, use $x^a<x^b\le 1$ and $1\le x^b\le x^a$ for $x<1$ and $x>1$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, I could just say that $f(x)=\Theta(x^{-2b})$ for $x\to 0$ and $f(x)=\Theta(x^{-2a})$ for $x\to\infty$ giving $b<1/2<a$?

Comment: @Jef yes that’s right

Answer (score 1):

The subtlety you're missing is the fact that the highest power is not always the dominating one. For instance, for $x$ close to $0$, we have $x^a\leq x^b$ when $b\leq a$, so that $(2x^b)^{-2}\leq (x^a+x^b)^{-2} \leq x^{-2b}$ in this range of $x$.